# OR style permissions for DjangoRestFramework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-permissions, django-rest-auth

I'm wondering if anyone has found a good way to *reverse* the way permissions work in DRF (use OR instead of AND). Right now, if any of the checks fail, the request is not authenticated. I would like a way to make it so that if any of the checks pass, the request *is* authenticated. ie.

```
# currently:
permission_classes=(HasNiceHat, HasNicePants)
```

Request will fail for anyone with a nice hat **and** pants. What I would like:

```
# goal:
AND_permission_classes=(HasNiceHat, HasNicePants)
```

Will succeed if user has nice hat **or** nice pants.

I will assume that all users are logged in (must be for either check to pass), and that implementation of the permission is not limited in any way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you just create your own permission class and use that?
For example:

```
from rest_framework import permissions

class HasNiceHatOrHasNicePants(permissions.BasePermission):
    """
    Permission to check if user has a Nice Hat or has Nice Pants.
    If both are False do not return anything.
    """
    def has_permission(self, request, view):

        if request.user.has_nicehat() or request.user.has_nicepants():
            return True
```

Then, import this new class into your view, and use it like this:

```
permission_classes = (HasNiceHatOrHasNicePants,)
```

---

It looks like [rest_condition](https://github.com/caxap/rest_condition) has the functionality that you need

Comment: This works, but there are many different combinations that are required, which is why this starts to become quite cumbersome.

Comment: ah, ok. I added a link to a library I just found that seems to do what you need (I have not used it)